# Amalgamating titles from checked checkboxes into string I can work with (put on clipboard etc)

Tags: .net, checkbox

Very much a beginner programmer (self taught with the aid of this site amongst others).

I have searched for the answer and found one on here that is painfully close but no cigar. I have linked it to a button press event as follows

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click    
 Dim chk As Control
 Dim txt As String = ""
  For Each chk In TabControl1.Controls
   If TypeOf chk Is CheckBox 
     If DirectCast(chk, CheckBox).Checked = True Then
       txt = txt + chk.Text +vbCrLF
     Else
       txt = replace(txt, chk.text + vbCrLf, "")
     End If
   End If 
  Next    
End Sub
```

It doesn't seem to add the text labels together into one long string as I hoped.

Can anyone help please ? I just want to be able to present a static list of options from which a custom checklist can be outputted depending on which boxes have been checked.

I have achieved this using validation on every checkbox individually, but there are approx 30 checkboxes so you can imagine how long my code is getting.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess vbCrLF is new line character. Did you try to remove that?

Comment: Hi Piyush - thanks for answering. Yes, I did try removing that and even replacing with environment.newline but it still didn't work.

Comment: Let me get this clearly. You want a single line output? Then why would you add environment.newline?

Comment: I was just after a list of the checkboxes checked that I could paste from the clipboard to another application. Doesn't have to be formatted in any way but I just liked the look of the one item per line approach - it was easier on the eyes of anyone looking back into the report.

Comment: Then the below answer should help you right? Did you try it?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering - I've been away from work where the PC with the program is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get all the checkboxes from the parent control and append/remove string values as per requirement.

```
 IEnumerable<CheckBox> checkboxes =  TabControl1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();
```

This will give you a collection of all your checkboxes and you can build your string based on the Checked property.

NOTE: This will only give you the immediate children of TabControl1 control. So if there are nested checkboxes you have to call this on all the parent controls.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I think I've found a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found using checkedlistbox and system.text.stringbuilder

Simply listing all my previously individual checkboxes in one checkedlistbox I managed to work out the following code to achieve my goal.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder

        For Each item In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems

            sb.Append(item)

         Next

    My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(sb.ToString)

end sub
```